# Successive Morphing Animation in SceneKit

Tags: ios, animation, swift2, scenekit, cabasicanimation

I struggle animating through different Morph-Targets in SceneKit.
I have an array of morph-targets I want to iterate through an show them with an animation between each of them.

So from one geometry to the other, this is easy.
In the [SCNMorpher Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMorpher_Class/index.html) there is an example to do this for one Morph-Geometry (morpher.weights[0]):

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "morpher.weights[0]")
animation.fromValue = 0.0;
animation.toValue = 1.0;
animation.autoreverses = true;
animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity;
animation.duration = 5;
```

What I want to do is, to animate the morphs successive. I tried to setup several animations, for each target. But after completing the first animation, the weight of the first target is set to 0 again.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()

    let vbasic_geom: [Vertex] = [
        [ [0, 0, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ],
        [ [0, 2, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ],
        [ [2, 2, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ]
    ]

    let vmorph1: [Vertex] = [
        [ [0, 0, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ],
        [ [0, 4, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ],
        [ [2, 2, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ]
    ]

    let vmorph2: [Vertex] = [
        [ [0, 0, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ],
        [ [0, 2, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ],
        [ [4, 2, 0],      [+1.0, +0.0, +0.0] ]
    ]


    let basic_geom = gen_geometry(vbasic_geom)

    let morph1 = gen_geometry(vmorph1)

    let morph2 = gen_geometry(vmorph2)


    let morpher = SCNMorpher()
    morpher.targets = [morph1, morph2]

    let object = SCNNode(geometry: basic_geom)
    object.morpher = morpher

    //needed for model-layer refresh; implicit animation
    morpher.setWeight(1.0, forTargetAtIndex: 0)
    morpher.setWeight(1.0, forTargetAtIndex: 1)

    //set up animations
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "morpher.weights[0]")
    animation.fromValue = 0.0
    animation.toValue = 1.0
    animation.duration = 5
    animation.beginTime = 0.0
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false

    let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "morpher.weights[1]")
    animation2.fromValue = 0.0;
    animation2.toValue = 1.0
    animation2.duration = 5
    animation2.beginTime = 5.0
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false

    let animationgroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animationgroup.duration = 10.0
    animationgroup.autoreverses = false
    animationgroup.repeatCount = 10000;

    animationgroup.animations = [animation, animation2]

    object.addAnimation(animationgroup, forKey: "morpher.weights")

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ1gb.gif) GIF

Tried several Solutions, but I never succeeded:

- Perhaps possible to change the ´keyPath: "morpher.weights[0]"´to ´morpher.weights´ and set the from- and toValues to something like an array. Including changing the valueFunction.
- Because the animations happens on the presentation-layer, it must be a way to preserve already animated properties to the finished value. It tried "removedOnCompletion", but doesn't seem to work.

Has anybody a clue or a solution?

I can post a link, to the whole code, if this is necessary - don't think it is asked for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem with CAAnimation - not just with SceneKit: explicit animations are removed on completion by default and the presentation value is reset to the model value (which is never modified by an explicit animation).
There are 2 solutions for that:

1. use an implicit animation instead (a SCNTransaction with a
   completion block that will trigger the next animation).
2. set removedOnCompletion to NO AND set the fillMode to FillForward.

optionally for #2: you can set a delegate to your animation, and remove the animation in animationDidStop after having sync'ed the modelValue to the presentationValue.